# ExecuteScalar and ExecuteNonQuery collision

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

i've got a problem with a `ExecuteScalar`, it doesn't allow to me to use a `ExecuteNonQuery` but i've got to execute two queryes to pick up the min date (dateStart9 and the max date(dateEnd) between the date range of the selected items of another table.

```
sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    //query date non va a causa dell'execute scalar
    SqlCommand cmdDS = new SqlCommand("SELECT MIN(DateStartSE) AS DATESE FROM tabStoreExec JOIN tabList ON tabStoreExec.idSE=tabList.idL WHERE tabList.selection=1", sqliteCon);
    SqlCommand cmdDE = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(DateEndSE) AS DATEED FROM tabStoreExec JOIN tabList ON tabStoreExec.idSE=tabList.idL WHERE tabList.selection=1", sqliteCon);
    cmdDS.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATESE", " DATESE");
    cmdDE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEED", "DATEED");
    cmdDS.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmdDE.ExecuteNonQuery();


  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tabStoricoDetail(NomeItem,ResItemDet,DateStartDet,DateEndDet) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES ('Prova','RProva',@DATESE,@DATEED)", sqliteCon);
  int generatedId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
  cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
  SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tabStoreExec SET FK_TSD_id = @tsdId FROM tabList JOIN tabStoreExec ON tabList.idL = tabStoreExec.idSE WHERE tabList.selection=1 ", sqliteCon);
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsdId", generatedId);
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Dato Aggiunto");

  }
  sqliteCon.Close();
```

I'm near the solution but the error is that [Declare the scalar variable "@DATESE".'
]

Comment: I don't think executing a `SELECT` query using `ExecuteNonQuery` is going to do anything at all. The query will execute but you won't get the result. Perhaps what you want is to use `ExecuteScalar` on the first two queries to actually get the results. It doesn't look like you need parameters for those queries.

Comment: the only problem is thast execute scalar can act only on the first item of the first row

Comment: When you do `SELECT MIN(DateStartSE)` you're selecting exactly one value. Your SELECT returns one row with one column. That's exactly the scenario where `ExecuteScalar` makes sense.

Comment: sorry you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should add the parameters to `cmd1` instad of `cmdDS` and `cmdDE`. You should call `ExecuteScalar()` to get a value back from these commands though:

```
SqlCommand cmdDS = new SqlCommand("SELECT MIN(DateStartSE) AS DATESE FROM tabStoreExec JOIN tabList ON tabStoreExec.idSE=tabList.idL WHERE tabList.selection=1", sqliteCon);
SqlCommand cmdDE = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(DateEndSE) AS DATEED FROM tabStoreExec JOIN tabList ON tabStoreExec.idSE=tabList.idL WHERE tabList.selection=1", sqliteCon);
var DATESE = cmdDS.ExecuteScalar();
var DATEED = cmdDE.ExecuteScalar();


SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tabStoricoDetail(NomeItem,ResItemDet,DateStartDet,DateEndDet) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES ('Prova','RProva',@DATESE,@DATEED)", sqliteCon);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATESE", DATESE);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEED", DATEED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parameters `@DATESE,@DATEED` to `cmd1` before executing it.